# How can I install ipipan corpus in nltk for Polish language in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I found that nltk contains some module for loading `ipipan` module but I can not load module - and it is not download list `nltk.download()`.

How can I attach `ipipan` for Polish language if it already include in nltk?

http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/ipipan.html

I was not found too much in Google.

[https://www.google.pl/search?q=ipipan+nltk](https://www.google.pl/search?q=ipipan%20nltk)

---

I tried such code but it produce exception and can not find ipipan:

```
from nltk import corpus
print dir(corpus.ipipan)

print corpus.ipipan.words()
```

Comment: I was downloaded data from link - it looks that is for `Poliqarp` but I try attach it - maybe it need some more experiments - I found also some nice page with Polish language resources - whatever `ipipan` is  enough for many usages. See this it looks very good: http://clip.ipipan.waw.pl/LRT

Comment: Probably ipipan corpus is not avaliable via nltk downloader, because of license, or bureaucracy in ipipan. So you should download it manually(from official site ofc) and put in you download directory.

Comment: I asked author of ipipan module about data but he not knows where is possible to download data. It is strange since author of module should know how to download data. I will asked him again about files maybe it is not dead code. I think that is not problem with license or copyright - it can be end of science program and it is not supported now or become obsolete - next nltk will contain modern Polish corpus whertever who knows when - http://nkjp.pl/index.php?page=0&lang=1 :)